# Program that is find the second max integer in Java (adding an option)

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have a code shown below that finds the second greatest number from command line.
For instance:

```
java FindSecondMax 3 4 5 6
```

The output will be second largest which is 5.

I want to display `There is no second largest number` when user enter same numbers. For example 4 4 4 4

How can I do this?

```
public class FindSecondMax {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int i = 1;
    while (i < args.length) {
        int nums =Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        if (nums > max)
        max = nums;
        i++;
    }
    int max1 = max;
    max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int j = 1;
    while (j < args.length ) {
        int nums = Integer.parseInt(args[j]);
        if (nums > max && nums < max1)
        max =nums;
        j++;
    }
    int max2 = max;
    System.out.println(max2);
    }
}
```

Comment: A fairly simple way to fit it into your code is to calculate a minimum in the first loop.  Then if min == max you have no second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change to your code is:

1. Capture the minimum value during the first loop where you calculate the max
2. Tell user there is no second max if (min==max) else ... do your former logic

   ```
   public class FindSecondMax {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

   int max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   int i = 1;
   while (i < args.length) {

       int nums = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

       if (nums > max)
           max = nums;
       if (nums < min)
           min = nums;
       i++;
   }

   if (min == max) {
       System.out.println("There is no secondmax");
   } else {
       int max1 = max;
       max = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       int j = 1;
       while (j < args.length) {
           int nums = Integer.parseInt(args[j]);

           if (nums > max && nums < max1)
               max = nums;
           j++;
       }
       int max2 = max;
       System.out.println(max2);
   }
   }
   }
   ```

Of note:  Sorting would help your approach.  The min/max is then trivial, and the second largest is a simple iteration from the largest down, until you get a different number.

Comment: Ok, the entire class is there now

Comment: Thanks this worked.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark as accepted, if this code meets your need.  Cheers

Answer (score -1):

just check to see if all the numbers are equal

```js
 if(isAllEqual(args)) {
      System.out.print("no second number");
    } else {
      System.out.print(max2);
    }
}//end of main
public static boolean isAllEqual(String[] cheese) {
   //figure out if each element in the array is equal
   boolean anw = true;
   for(int i = 1; i < cheese.length;i++) {
   //put some code here
   //if you find out there not equl
   //anw = false;
   //break;
   }
   return anw;
}
```

Comment: this isn't "a do my homework site" but ill try to point you in a direction with the answer above